# Angular 4 - Post request with Map not working

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to post Map data from angular 4 app to spring boot server but its not working, can someone please help?

Service-->

```js
  getmapdata(): Observable<ITinyMCEData[]> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let data = new Map<number, string>();
    data.set(1, 'aa');
    data.set(2, 'bb');
    data.set(3, 'cc');

    console.log('map value == ' + data.get(1));

    return this._http.post(this._testmapurl, data, options)
      .map((response: Response) => <ITinyMCEData[]> response.json())
      .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));
  }
```

chrome browser is not displaying the map data:

```
Request Payload
{}
No Properties
```

Server is getting blank data:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/testmap", method =  RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<User> getMapData(@RequestBody Map<Integer, String> data) {
    System.out.println("Data = " + data); --> display blank
    Iterator entries = data.entrySet().iterator();
    while (entries.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
        Integer key = (Integer)entry.getKey();
        Integer value = (Integer)entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("Key == " + key + " value == + " + value);
    }

    User user = new User();
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. Map type is only supported in ES6 and it seems my browser doesn't support ES6. So I replaced my map implementation to 
let map = {}; and then populating values.
On the server I have created a class that contains the map.